# Why I can't see the screen borders?

Tags: nvidia, video, screen, samsung

I have install Ubuntu 11.10 on my PC and all goes right except the screen. I can't see the borders of the screen, especially up and down.

I have an Nvidia Geforce GT220 connected to a Samsung TV with hdmi.

Comment: Have you changed the display resolution on your TV to match your computer? I have my 11.10 hooked up to an LG and that's what I had to do at first. Sometimes I have to use the autoconfig in the tv's display menu to center it up.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with my 2006 samsung tv. 
Try to change the resolution .
You can try openning the nvidia control panel go to the gpu section last item (that shows your samsung tv name) and paly with the stretching :-) it should work.